# Sharepoint 2013 - Issue with the embed code webpart and an inserted <script></script>

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Recently, when i  try to insert a script /script into a embed code web part it just make it disappear (not the code... the all webpart!). Just like the "Embed code webpart" does not want to be turned into  a "Script Editor Webpart".

**I've check the webpart maintenance page (?contents=1) : It's empty.**

1 - [Loading after inserting the script /script (ie : bootstrap.js)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzowh.png)

2 - [The page reload and the Embed code webpart just disapear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8zE9.png)

When i insert only html it work fine...

Comment: Try to ask this here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: try script editor webpart?